# Monero GUI - Is Daemon blocks remaining accurate when using --prune-blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, pruning

When using the `--prune-blockchain` flag in the Monero GUI, the "Daemon blocks remaining" message still seems to start as the number of blocks in the full (unpruned) ledger. Is this normal? The number of blocks remaining linearly decreases over time, but perhaps we are still skipping over some blocks aka pruning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Daemon blocks remaining accurate when using --prune-blockchain?

Yes. The amount of blocks you must sync, verify and scan is the same regardless if pruning or not.

Pruning just affects how much data is *stored*.

> The number of blocks remaining linearly decreases over time, but perhaps we are still skipping over some blocks aka pruning?

Per above. We are not skipping downloading, verifying or scanning, we just don't *save* all the block data when pruning.

> Is this normal?

Yes.